# Работа с датой в ado.net/sql/c#

Tags: access, c#, база-данных, sql

Вот пишу программу на C# WinForms, БД подключаю из Access, в БД есть две таблицы:
Users (Таблица с именами)
simens (Таблица, в которой с полями "Дата/время прихода", "Дата/время ухода" и "Индекс имени из первой таблицы")")

Стандартная ставка равна 9 в час при 9 часовом рабочем дне. Если работник проработал например день не 9, а 8 часов, значит требуется это отнять от его ставки. Ставку нужно вывести в dataGridView по каждому имени.

Направьте на путь истинный, каким образом это все реализовывать, возможно ли это все запросом sql записать или все же придется реализовывать средствами C#, или возможно воспользоваться Linq можно. Помогите.

Comment: 1) любым подходящим способом, большой разницы в описываемом случае нет

2) поменяйте заголовок вопроса, отношения к работе с датами вопрос не имеет

Comment: желательно запросом, но большие запросы я составлять не умею, может поможет кто?

Comment: Учитывая бедноватые возможности движка Access по вычислениям в SQL -- думаю что вам нужно делать расчёты в C#.